# How do I share a dictionary of locks in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing and am trying to prevent simultaneous updates to a number of resources (for example files), each identified by a name. I do not know all names in advance.
Therefore I am trying to use

```
class A:
    resource_locks_lock = RLock()
    resource_locks = {}  # type: Dict[str, RLock]

    def some_method(self, name: str) -> None
        with A.resource_locks_lock:
            if name not in A.resource_locks.keys():
                A.resource_locks[name] = RLock()
            A.resource_locks[name].acquire()
            [...]
            A.resource_locks[name].release()
```

However, that does not prevent multiple instances of this class in separate processes (using python multiprocessing) from accessing the locked resource simultaneously. It seems each process gets its own version of the dictionary and the locks.

What do I need to do to prevent simultaneous access across python multiprocessing boundaries?

Comment: Have a look at the multiprocessing [`Manager.dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). This allows several processes to share a single dictionary object. It might be sufficient for what you need.

Comment: You could lock the files themselves. There are operating system dependencies and other issues. I used `lockfile` back in the day, but I noticed that its pypi docs say it is deprecated in favor of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasteners.